# EF code first define FK correctly (1/0 to 1/0)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am not able to define the following DB structure, using navigation properties:

```
    Table: Batch
    PK: Id
    FK: Model_ID (can be also null)

    Table: Model
    PK: Id
    no FKs related to Batch
```

So this is something like 1/0 to 1/0 relationship. Both `Model` & `Batch` can exists without knowing each other. Note that I need FK column only in 'Batch' and not in 'Model'. In 'Model' I just want to get related `Batch` if it exists. But some models and some batches are connected to each other.

I have defined the following, but it is

```
public class BaseData {
     public Guid Id {get; set; }     
     public Guid? ModelId {get; set; }
     public ModelData ModelId { get; set; }
}

public class ModelData {
     public Guid Id {get; set; }
     public Guid? BatchId { get; set; }
     public BatchData Batch { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to define correct DB structure if I remove one navigation property - 
`BatchData Batch` from `ModelData`.
However, I would like to have navigation properties in both classes, is it possible?

I have tried different configs, neither works.
One example I've tried:

ModalConfig:

HasOptional(x => x.Batch)
      .WithRequired(x => x.Model);

BatchConfig:

```
 HasOptional(x => x.Model)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

This doesn't creates FKs in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent PK id is also FK id.

```
public class BatchData {
     [ForeignKey("Model")]
     public Guid Id {get; set; }     
     // public Guid? ModelId {get; set; }
     // public ModelData ModelId { get; set; }
     public ModelData Model { get; set; }
}
```

Principal can't have FK id in the model.

```
public class ModelData {
     public Guid Id {get; set; }
     // public Guid? BatchId { get; set; }
     public BatchData Batch { get; set; }
}
```

That will work without fluent api configuration.